# disable histexpand and variable substitution

Tags: bash, shell

I need to create many thousands of files and I have no control over the text strings that need to be used for the paths and names. Trouble is, these strings might contain ",',“,‘,! or $, all of which can cause problems.

I can replace all quotes with the normal apostrophe, but I want to keep any $ or ! characters and so far not been able to figure how to do this.

Set +H will turn off history expansion, but I cannot make it work within the same command. So:-

```
set +H; echo "Hi, this is $10 Tom!"
```

still generates the error due to the !. If I run them as 2 separate commands, histexpand stays off and it works, but running them both just separated by the ; does NOT change histexpand.

The problem is that the commands will be run in their own shell and I can't seem to run multiple lines (doShellScript in Apple's JXA) so need them on the same line just separated by the ;.

So how can I make the set +H stick for the immediately following command?

Also, is it possible to stop the shell from interpreting $ as preceding a variable and just deal with it as a regular character? I can't just quote the whole string with single quotes since it may contain ' within itself.

Suggestions?

Comment: Wrt stopping it interpreting `$` and also being able to use `'`, you can use an ansi c string `$'\'\'$10'` would print `''$10`

Comment: How are you getting the strings? This isn't an issue with parameter expansion; `foo` can contain anything and `printf '%s\n' "$foo"` would work properly. If these are hard-coded strings, use single quotes. If you are using `eval` somewhere, stop :).

Comment: I am now passing the strings through a function that escapes and quotes any in-line apostrophes and then single quotes the entire string and this avoids the $ problem. Fortunately from within the AppleScript environment, !/histexpand doesn't seem to be a problem. It was the in-line apostrophes that were throwing errors. However I would still like to know how to be able to turn histexpand OFF for a single command.

Comment: This is an excellent question and I'm surprised nobody has answered it. The reason is in the interpreter; history expansion would happen *before* any command execution begins. That's why there is a difference in behavior when you run `set +H; echo "Hi, this is $10 Tom!"` on the same line - the shell never gets a chance to disable history expansion.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46614716/render-curly-braces-as-plain-text-in-react-jsx