# Render curly braces as plain text in React/JSX

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I am having problems displaying { and } as text in React. I saw a similar question that someone said to wrap the entire string in curlies, but this is not working:

```
let queries_block = this.state.previous_queries.map((dataset) => {
            return (<p>{"{{}}"}<p>)
        });

        if (results) {
            results_block = (
                <div>
                    <p>Queries:</p>
                    {queries_block}
                    <br/><br/>
                    <p>Results: {results_count}</p>
                    <JSONPretty id="json-pretty" json={results}></JSONPretty>
                </div>
            );
        } else {
            results_block = null;
        }
```

The `return (<p>{"{{}}"}<p>)` causes

```
ERROR in ./src/components/app.js
Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token, expected } (47:13)

  45 |                     <JSONPretty id="json-pretty" json={results}></JSONPretty>
  46 |                 </div>
> 47 |             );
     |              ^
  48 |         } else {
  49 |             results_block = null;
  50 |         }

 @ ./src/index.js 15:11-38
webpack: Failed to compile.
```

Is there an easy way to escape curly braces in jsx?

Answer (score 76, accepted):

I think the issue is just a typo. You have this:

```
return (<p>{"{{}}"}<p>)
```

but you need this (note the closing `p` tag instead of another opening one):

```
return (<p>{"{{}}"}</p>)
```

Answer (score 126):

If you'd like to render curly braces as plain text within a JSX document simply use the HTML character codes.

Left Curly Brace { : `&#123;`

Right Curly Brace } : `&#125;`

Answer (score 10):

You can even use string interpolation in ES6.
Template literals are string literals allowing embedded expressions. You can use multi-line strings and string interpolation features with them.
Template literals are enclosed by the backtick (` `)  (grave accent) character instead of double or single quotes.

```
eg: return (<p>{`{{}}`}</p>)
```

Comment: I was about to suggest this before I saw your answer. Yet another way is to use `JSON.stringify`. e.g. `<pre>{JSON.stringify(result, null, 4)}</pre>` is a quick and dirty way to print JSON.

Answer (score 8):

If you are in a situation where you can't use `&#123;` and `&#125;`, then you can use custom code:

```js
export default class Component extends React.Component {
  render () {
    return (
      Some object {'{'}id: 1{'}'}
    )
  }
}
```

Which will output the text `Some object {id: 1}`

Update: Changed it to a better solution, thanks to @xec

Comment: Why not just `Some object {'{'}id: 1{'}'}`

Answer (score 0):

You can also render curly braces with a variable as well. For example :

```
const curlyBraces = '{}';
return This is an example for {cusrlyBraces} rendered in JSX
```