# how to use curly brackets without it being an expression in react

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I need to have something like

```
<p>{</p>
// code
<p>}</p>
```

How can i use the curly parenthesis without it erroring and say expression needed?
Is there an escape character that i can use? i.e. `"\""`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Render curly braces as plain text react/jsx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46614716/render-curly-braces-as-plain-text-react-jsx)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Well, this is a pretty solution. use the same curly brackets for display curly brackets.

```
 {'{'} {'}'}
```

Comment: I thought of that the moment I submitted the question. Thanks!

Comment: I think using @G4bri3l solution is a good choice. Over this concatenation.

Answer (score 4):

I know there's already plenty of answers but just for completion, I recommend using semantic HTML, in this case I am talking specifically about the `code` tag (see docs [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/code)):

```
<code>{`{ hello }`}</code>
```

You can use the backtick to avoid the use of many single or double quotes.